# Adding 'Original' URL for Custom links

Tags: menus

I have a menu with custom links with the section of URL, however if I want to change the URL(to remove it) for some page(Sample Page) I can not, because I must provide specific URL. I want to put 'Original'(Original: Sample Page) from page link, to my custom link. How do I do this, please?

Answer (score 0):

1 Insert the page link 
2 Right click on "original" and copy URL Address
3 Remove the page link
4 Insert Custom Link and past the Url Address

Comment: Not good. If I change the address in All Pages, this will not change the link I add to my custom-link. But the link in the 'Original' will change relatively to what I changed in the All Pages link.

Answer (score -1):

Just, go to all pages and remove a page. And create your one with name "Sample Page".

Comment: No, this is not what I am asking for. I want to link to the page(Sample Page) with custom link.

Comment: you can go to all pages, cick on "sample page" and under the title you will se the link of that page...there you can edit link

Comment: You not understand. If I change the address in All Pages, this will not change the link I add to my custom-link. But the link in the 'Original' will change relatively to what I changed in the All Pages link.